# What is the most optimized way of implementing computed fields using Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, fluent-interface, computed-field

I am using Entity Framework/Fluent API and I am new to them. In my scenario I am having the following three classes.

```
public class Review
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public float AverageRating { get; private set; } //Computed Field
    public int TotalLikes { get; private set; } //Computed Field
    public List<Rating> Ratings { get; private set;}
    public List<Like> Likes { get; private set;}
}
public class Rating
{
    public int CustomerId { get; private set; }
    public int ReviewId { get; private set; }
    public int Rating { get; set; }
}
public class Like
{
    public int CustomerId { get; private set; }
    public int ReviewId { get; private set; }
}
```

I have Fluent mapping for all three classes and their relationships. In the review class I have two computed fields. I could populate computed fields from child collections (Ratings and Likes). In that case in the Linq query I have to include both child collections, which I believe is a performance intensive operation. Alternatively I could also use computed columns in the DB. But I don't like to put anything in the database side. So, what is the best way of populating the computed fields (mostly aggregate operations like Count, Average, etc) without loading the child collections or using a database solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a database solution like a stored procedure or using computed columns on the database side then this leaves us with one option i guess. That is have a method in your repository like `GetRatings()` or something similar and use a linq query in that method to compute ratings, of course LINQ to Entities will convert that Linq query to a native SQL query which should be faster as it is native to the database.

Answer (score 0):

> With out using Database solution...

Linq has count/max/average,Sum,groupby,distinct .... etc So Pulling data back once the DB has "calculated it", such as a count or sum integer isnt normally an issue. 
So no need to drag back all objects.

The use of concurrency checking to keep integrity when posting back . ie Timestamp EF type Rowversion, Will be necessary

Basically with EF you put a value in the context and SAY Save.
So the key thing to remember is when Saving, how to make sure the data is OK.
Thats the role of the Rowversion. (optimistic locking)

If the record you are changing **has** changed since you read it, fail.
You re-read/recalc and try again.

However, if your application demands pessimistic locking
then [this article from Ladislav is recommended reading](http://www.ladislavmrnka.com/2012/09/entity-framework-and-pessimistic-concurrency/)
Essentially EF doesnt offer Pessimistic locking.

HOWEVER, you can call the DB using methods exposed on EF, or just call the DB.

```
Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand()
```

Note by default EF does not read Dirty data.(ie no uncommitted read)

After all that you still need/want pessimistic locking semaphore style to access to the data.
then see [Application Lock on SQL server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx)

YEP you will need the DB, unless you have an ENQUEUE server handy;-)